# Is Master Page concept available in Active reports 9?

Tags: activereports

Hey Hi Every one can any one help me out,

I am using Active Reports 9 in C# ,  and very much new to this. I want to generate multiple reports suppose for example say 'Menu items' and 'Menu costs'. I want same Header and footer for all my reports. I searched and goggled but is this possible if possible how ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a report using c# with Active Reports?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23652426/how-to-create-a-report-using-c-sharp-with-active-reports)

Comment: Tim Ogilvy , Thanks for replying but the main problem am facing is we have set of reports and we are developing it properly. But all the reports have same contents in Header and footer including Logo and few text fields , can i have a common layout so that i need not to develop similar content in all the reports,  Like how we use Master page concept in Asp.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the concept of Master Reports in both Section Reports and Page Reports,  that will give you exactly what you're looking.   So in addition to the link you provided you have Master Reports with Content Areas similar to Master Pages in ASP.NET
[Master Reports](http://arhelp.grapecity.com/webhelp/AR10/index.html#MasterReports(RDL).html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Grape city Team.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Tim Ogilvy, your posted link helped me to Find what i need.

Here is the Link http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR8Help/AR8_HelpOnlineEN/InheritaMasterReportSection.html

Every thing is in Deatil how to make common layout in Active reports.